# does the Google crawler waits the page to be finalized before indexing?

Tags: seo, polymer, search-engine, web-component, shadow-dom

I recently decided to code my websites using **Polymer** library *(WebComponents*).

The common structure of a webcomponents-based application/website is to encapsulate the structure in a app-like element like the following :

```
<my-app></my-app>
```

and makes a file for every customized elements belonging to the application.
Polymer is so useful and can also be used to organize and program basic webpages or websites. I have one wonder though.

Because all the information used for **microdata** referencing and for indexation is contained in the shadow-dom of the main element of the application, any crawler would just fetch the page and just see `<my-app></my-app>` in the body (or is it just my imagination ?).
Then

> is the Google crawler capable of reading the dom-shadow ?

In other words is the crawler acting like a real user and waiting the page to be all stable and waits all the Dom tree to be rendered like the one we could deal with when we open the developer-tool window on chrome browser ?

This is a very important point since all the microdata is used for the main semantic of the page/application and thus for making one's website to be well referenced in any search-engine.

Comment: Some few years ago there was information that google follows js links on page. So maybe google renders some js for dom elements. If i remember correctly there is a function `fetch as googlebot`  in google webmaster console so if you have a domain that you can verify as yours, then you could see what is indexed by googlebot

Comment: @Jask I tried `fetch as googlebot` feature, the result is nothing but the plain html page that first loads before applying any JavaScript code to my dom.

Comment: @ballangddang I'm facing the same issue. Have you made any progress on this?

Comment: https://twitter.com/LeaVerou/status/931996134343667712

Answer (score 0):

If by finalize, you mean all JS is executed, then the answer is no, not necessarily. Google bots can sometimes first only consider the content of your page without JS execution. Later, they can come back and wait for the full execution of JS.

If your website is not spammy, using forbidden techniques, etc. then bots will surely analyse the JS version of your pages, it's a matter of time.